# How to get the position of element index of an array in an ascending order?

Tags: javascript, html

let a=[4, 3, 2, 2, 0, 1]

let b=[0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4]; //My code demo below help to sort a into ascending order.

**Output**=[4, 5, 2, 3, 1, 0];
// Get the position of element index in a ascending order. For example, 0 is in index 4, 1 is in index 5, 2 is in index 2,2 is in index 3, and 4 is in index 0. Please Provide a demo. Thank you

```js
var Arr = [4, 3, 2, 2, 0, 1];

for (var i = 1; i < Arr.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    if (Arr[i] < Arr[j]) {
      var x = Arr[i];
      Arr[i] = Arr[j];
      Arr[j] = x;
    }
  }
}


console.log(Arr);
```

Comment: I formatted your snippet and added some `{}` for readability

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is called bubble sort. Check this article for explanation and working js example - https://medium.com/javascript-algorithms/javascript-algorithms-bubble-sort-3d27f285c3b2

Answer (score 2):

You could get the indices of the unsorted array and sort the indices by the values of the array.

```js
const
    array = [4, 3, 2, 2, 0, 1],
    indices = [...array.keys()];

indices.sort((a, b) => array[a] - array[b]);

console.log(...indices);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Object.entries` :

```js
let a=[4, 3, 2, 2, 0, 1]

let result = Object.entries(a).sort((a,b) => a[1]-b[1]).map(e => +e[0])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess this is what you want 
and also i change some other thing in code to be cleaner and readable
you can ask me anything if you want

```
function sortWithIndex (self) {
  let Arr = [4, 3, 2, 2, 0, 1];
  let result = [];
  let ArrLength = Arr.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < ArrLength; i++) {
    number = Arr[i];
    indexOfNumber = i;
    result.push ('index ' + indexOfNumber + ' is ' + number);
    };
  return result  
  };
console.log(sortWithIndex());
```

Mostafa.T